# Where is the actual documentation for the composer python SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

Am I crazy or is this documentation non-existent: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/composer/latest

"Code samples and snippets live in the samples/ folder." What samples folder?

The repo also has nothing: https://github.com/googleapis/python-orchestration-airflow

Any documentation anywhere? I'd like to experiment with calling the composer APIs through a python script instead of the gcloud cli.

Example snippets for simple stuff like creating, listing, and updating environment with the python SDK.

## EDIT

Per comments there appear to be samples here, but they seem to only be for V1? I'm using composer V2. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-orchestration-airflow/samples/generated_samples/composer_v1_generated_environments_update_environment_async.py

Comment: Oh geeze, the "Read the Client Library Documentation" link under "Next Steps" just links right back to the same page you're already on.

Comment: [These](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-orchestration-airflow/samples/generated_samples) *might* be the samples they're talking about? They're no substitute for proper documentation either way, though.

Comment: I think if you look at the sidebar on the left, and navigate the tree under "google-cloud-orchestration-airflow > Orchestration", those might be the docs you're looking for.

Comment: 1) All companies have documentation that sometimes breaks. Perhaps consider clicking the feedback button on the page at the bottom and letting someone know. 2) Google published their examples on GitHub. You can download repositories with a large number of examples for many languages, SDKs, and frameworks. Start [here](https://github.com/google) or [here](https://github.com/googleapis). Use the search feature to find what want. For [example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-orchestration-airflow).

Comment: In your post, you reference a repository. That repository has been moved and there is a notice that tells you that. The new repository has many [examples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-orchestration-airflow/samples/generated_samples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @user2357112  and @John Hanley the "Read the Client Library Documentation" link under "Next Steps" just links right back to the same page you're already on.

Google published their examples on `GitHub`. You can download repositories with a large number of examples for many languages, SDKs, and frameworks. Start here or here. Use the search feature to find what you want. For example .

The samples are available [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-orchestration-airflow/samples/generated_samples)

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.